# I can't install any software in ubuntu 20.10

Tags: apt, updates

I Can't Install any software :(
my software center is disappeared
and when I use packages like apt
for example when I want to install vlc

`sudo apt install vlc`

I get this error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package vlc
```

I tried to add `sudo apt-update` before the installing  I got

```
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/mpv-tests/ubuntu groovy InRelease        
Err:2 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                  
  Cannot initiate the connection to dl.google.com:443 (2a00:1450:4019:805::200e). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to dl.google.com:443 (216.58.208.238), connection timed out
Err:3 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                
  Connection failed [IP: 104.214.230.139 80]
Err:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/groovy/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
W: Failed to fetch https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to dl.google.com:443 (2a00:1450:4019:805::200e). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to dl.google.com:443 (216.58.208.238), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code/dists/stable/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 104.214.230.139 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I Tried may thing  If you get the same error please help me

Comment: Upgrade to a supported release (like 21.10).You are using 20.10, which is EOL, and so [is off-topic here](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic). Sorry.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/07/25/ubuntu-20-10-groovy-gorilla-end-of-life-reached-on-july-22-2021/ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: FYI:  **After** a release goes EOL; its software repository is moved (refer prior comment) thus software cannot be installed until you've *manually* altered your system to point to the *moved* location.  It's not automatic; as you're supposed to have *release-upgraded* before the EOL occurs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How upgrade Ubuntu 20.10 after its EOL?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1361262/how-upgrade-ubuntu-20-10-after-its-eol)

Answer (score 1):

Check that your Ubuntu machine really has Internet access, i.e. appropriate network interface is enabled and properly configured, cable plugged in, wifi spot is available, etc. Because this error message `connect (101: Network is unreachable)` says you don't have it for some reason.

Comment: No, it actually means what was mentioned in comments: *After a release goes EOL; its software repository is moved*

Comment: What about things like this: Err:3 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                
  Connection failed [IP: 104.214.230.139 80]

Comment: Of course after having internet connection it may come up that repo moved, but the very first problem to solve seems to be really inet connection.