# apt-get update error: missing release how can I update/upgrade?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, repository

I have ubuntu 20.10 and try to upgrade. I do

```
 sudo apt-get upgrade
```

but get an error

```
E: Il repository "http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy Release" non ha più un file Release.
N: L'aggiornamento da tale repository non può essere eseguito in modo sicuro ed è quindi disabilitato come impostazione predefinita.
N: Consultare la pagina man apt-secure(8) per la creazione di un repository e la configurazione utente.
E: Il repository "http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates Release" non ha più un file Release.
N: L'aggiornamento da tale repository non può essere eseguito in modo sicuro ed è quindi disabilitato come impostazione predefinita.
N: Consultare la pagina man apt-secure(8) per la creazione di un repository e la configurazione utente.
E: Il repository "http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-backports Release" non ha più un file Release.
N: L'aggiornamento da tale repository non può essere eseguito in modo sicuro ed è quindi disabilitato come impostazione predefinita.
N: Consultare la pagina man apt-secure(8) per la creazione di un repository e la configurazione utente.
E: Il repository "http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security Release" non ha un file Release.
N: L'aggiornamento da tale repository non può essere eseguito in modo sicuro ed è quindi disabilitato come impostazione predefinita.
N: Consultare la pagina man apt-secure(8) per la creazione di un repository e la configurazione utente.
```

which, in english sounds as

```
repository "http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy Release" no longer has a Release file.
...
```

How can I update/updgrade my system?

Comment: **groovy** is **20.10** and it reached EOL on July 22 2021

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/07/25/ubuntu-20-10-groovy-gorilla-end-of-life-reached-on-july-22-2021/ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: @Raffa thanks, changed in the question

Comment: The problem is that I cannot upgrade because first I need to update

Comment: Please see: [How upgrade Ubuntu 20.10 after its EOL?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1361262)

Comment: You can fresh install Ubuntu 22.04 instead of upgrading so many times. It is an LTS release, and you can continue using it till 2027 without upgrading.

Comment: If it's a desktop system, you can re-install without losing any data files, and having *manually installed* packages (from Ubuntu repositories) auto-reinstalled (if available in the new release) automatically. The lack of format triggers this type of install; available with `calamares` or `ubiquity` installer ISOs of Ubuntu.  As system directories are wiped; server apps (which can store *conf* files in those directories) aren't catered for (desktop apps store configs in $HOME which isn't touched unless you format).

Comment: @guiverc how can I do that?

Comment: @Raffa the question you linked about EOL worked

Comment: Now I'm upgrading to 21.04 -> 21.10 -> 22.04 but yes, if I coud do a fresh install in the way @guiverc says I'll be happier: how can I do that? (Is there any question answering that could be linked here?)

Comment: Re-install allows you to go forward/backwards though of course there can be complications compared to a *release-upgrade*, but it's my fall back if I have problems with a *release-upgrade*, or I just lack the time/energy to *release-upgrade* as re-install is so quick. The lack of format triggers the *upgrade via re-install* (or "*install using existing partition*" as per Lubuntu testcase).  I document it [here](https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/testing-checklist-understanding-the-testcases/2743) though that's intended for QA-testers not end-users.. I've written about it here (20+ times) too

Answer (score 0):

I found that [How upgrade Ubuntu 20.10 after its EOL?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1361262) solved my first problem.

I found useful also the comment of guiverc about re-istalling without losing the "history" of packages installed. Basically by chosing from isntalling media via the option that don't format partitions. [here](https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/testing-checklist-understanding-the-testcases/2743) the link from guiverc comment.