# System won't start after update is installed

Tags: updates, kubuntu, 22.04

I updated my Kubuntu from 21.04 to 22.04 and then updated it. Here is a screenshot with the list of updates:

[image]

It installs everything and then demands to restart. When I'm trying to reboot the system it just stuck on motherboard logo. I had to restore the system using `timeshift`

What should I do to update, or should I skip these updates altogether somehow?

----- Update 04.03.2023 -----
Today I tried to start system after shut down and it stuck on the same motherboard logo. I didn't even install any updates before this. However

However, as user535733 suggested, I booted from USB drive and run `boot-repair`. The only thing that did is allowed me to select OS version before going to the same motherboard logo. Had to restore system from Timeshift backup again

Boot-Repair generated this [link](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/D23BqVCWdc/)

Comment: [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1413693/1222991) will provide you the steps required to upgrade from an unsupported EOL release to something more recent 

Comment: @matigo Ok, I'll try that. Though `22.04` is latest LTS version, so it is strange it is considered EOL release

Comment: 22.04 is fine. 21.04 is the EOL release 

Comment: @matigo I updated to `22.04` successfully, but later I updated modules from software update center (Discover on kubuntu), the list is on the screenshot. And after that it asked me to reboot and just stuck on motherboard logo screen

Comment: @guiverc I did not upgrade my system using `sudo do-release-upgrade` command, I just installed a new version `22.04` using usb boot drive

Comment: "*When I'm trying to reboot the system it just stuck on motherboard logo*" suggests a problem with GRUB. Read your upgrade output carefully for any errors. After the upgrade, try boot-repair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the issue was solved by executing the following steps:

- Updated grub: `sudo update-grub`
- Installed all the updates excluding UEFI dbx
- Installed UEFI dbx with `sudo fwupdmgr update`
- Ubuntu started normally after reboot.